# Solve a second order homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve following second order ODE, But I am almost stuck :

$$\frac{\partial ^2\sigma}{\partial x^2}-h(x) \sigma=0$$

where $h(x)$ define as:
$$h(x)=G_o+\left(G_{\infty }-G_o\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi }\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 \mathcal{D} m^2 t}{L^2}}\frac {\cos (\pi  m)-1}{m}\sin \left(\frac{\pi  m \left(\frac{L}{2}+x\right)}{L}\right)\right)$$
where $G_{\infty }$, $G_o$, $t$, $L$ and $D$ are positive constant number.

with Boundary Conditions: 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \left\{\sigma\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)=0\right\}&,\left\{\sigma\left(-\frac{L}{2}\right)=c\right\} \\\end{array}\right)$$

I will appreciate for any help.

Comment: Do you think it has a "closed form" solution?

Comment: I don't know. I am looking for close form if exist. For simplification lets consider two terms of series.

Comment: Because of linearity it's enough to consider this equation with any term of form $\alpha \sin \left ( \frac{\pi m \left ( \frac{L}{2} + x \right )}{L} \right )$.